# how to not insert extra space at the end or beginning of space separated strings

Tags: java

I want to represent a list `[1,2,3,4]` like `"\"1 2 3 4\""`. Note the escaped quotes and the lack of a space between them and their neighbouring numbers. How can I achieve this? It's such a trivial thing, but it's tricky since I'm working with a TreeSet, not an array. Is this even possible with a for loop or do I have to resort to using the TreeSet iterator?

```
public String positionsRep(TreeSet<Integer> positions){
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("");
    s.append("\"");
    for(Integer pos: positions){
        posStr = Integer.toString(pos);
        s.append(posStr);
        s.append(" ");
    }   
    s.append("\"");
    return s.toString();
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current implementation?

Comment: It adds an extra space before the last quote mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just treat the first number a bit differently:

```
public String positionsRep(TreeSet<Integer> positions){
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("");
    s.append("\"");
    boolean isFirst = true;
    for(Integer pos: positions){
        if (!isFirst) {
            s.append(" ");
        }
        posStr = Integer.toString(pos);
        s.append(posStr);
        isFirst = false;
    }   
    s.append("\"");
    return s.toString();
}
```

However, it might be better to just use a [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) instead of the `StringBuilder`, it does exactly what you want if initialized with `(" ", "\"", "\"")`. This should look somehow like that:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ", "\"", "\"");
for (Integer i: positions) {
    sj.add(i.toString());
}
String result = sj.toString();
```

Or even shorter using streams:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

positions.stream().map(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(" ", "\"", "\""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an Array from that TreeSet and the use the string properties to join the elements by a space and then add the special char that you need

Example:

```
TreeSet<String> playerSet = new TreeSet<String>();
    playerSet.add("1");
    playerSet.add("2");
    playerSet.add("3");
    playerSet.add("4");

    StringBuilder sr = new StringBuilder();
    sr.append("\"").append(String.join(" ", new ArrayList<String> (playerSet))).append("\"");
    System.out.println(sr.toString());
```